# Calling an array within an array for Chef Attributes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to get a Chef recipe built for a series of Registry_keys. They are all being hosted within the chef attributes default.rb. I'm trying to call the defined attribute and `create_if_missing` each key.

Examples of the code are as follows.

Chef `attribute\default.rb`

```
default['randomhost']['registry']['entries'] = [
  { 
    'Key' => 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RandomApplication', 
    'Values' => [
      {
        name: 'RandomValueName', 
        type: :qword, 
        data: 1 
      }, { 
        name: 'RandomValueName2', 
        type: :qword, 
        data: 2
      }
    ] 
  }
]
```

Chef `Recipe\registryKey.rb`

```
node['randomhost']['registry']['entries'].each do |item|
  registry_key item['Key'] do
    values item['Values']
    recursive true
    action :create_if_missing # Default
  end
end
```

When I go to build this out, calling the `item['Values']` claims that

```
Bad key name in RegistryKey values hash
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is as `name:`, `type:`, and `data:` are all symbols in the attributes array.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: Are those the actual values you are using or did you redact them?

Comment: I don't think mixing two hash notation is a good idea at all. See the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_registry_key.html#syntax) for example

Comment: The values had been redacted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was running into was that the nested array was converting the symbols into strings. I had to rebuild the array within my recipe using the `.map` method.

Chef `Recipe\registryKey.rb`

```
node['randomhost']['registry']['entries'].each do |item|
  my_array = item['Values'].map { |key| 
    { 
     name: key['name'], 
     type: key['type'], 
     data: key['data'] 
    } 
  }
  registry_key item['Key'] do
    values my_array
    recursive true
    action :create_if_missing # Default
  end
end
```